# Web.config modification in multi server farm

Tags: multiple-farms

i have a Sharepoint web app which has web.config modification.when i do it in single server farm, it works very fine but when i do the same thing in multi server farm which has 10 servers(2 WFE,2 APP and 6 search), it doesnt work as expected.

```
<modules>
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
</modules>
```

This is the modification i do. please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Follow all the steps here to make sure you have everything covered. You may have missed something.

Step by Step – Enable ASP.NET Session State on SharePoint 2010 Application
http://nikpatel.net/2012/02/12/enable-asp-net-session-state-on-sharepoint-2010-application/